# Adblock removed but still ads are blocked

Tags: browser, browser-addons, browser-cache, adblock

Everyone, can you help with this:

[image: Something wrong with this website]

I have removed adblock but the ads are still not displayed on that website (www.thefreedictionary.com). Changing browser and restored from 2 weeks ago didn't help. It is very annoying.

Comment: What browser? try clearing the cache. Chrome especially caches error messages and keeps redisplaying them long after the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cleaned content licenses and hosted app data and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I clean the cookies, caches, hosted app data, content licenses and browsing histories and finally it works! It is still very strange for me but anyway it is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset** the browser to its **default settings** or use `incognito mode` browser. Make sure to try with `translate.google.com` which will not go **ad-blocking** inspection.

Paste your website in **translate.google.com** and then `from` language make it **Spanish** or **non-English** and then click on `to` language `hyperlink`. This should work